# Problems in parsing XML file using R

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to parse a XML file to CSV using R. I am using the XML library to do it. Please find below the code

```
library(XML)
a<-xmlParse(file.choose())
library(plyr)
ldply(xmlToList(a), function(x) { data.frame(x[!names(x)==""]) } )
```

Sample Data Below

```
   <SSE xmlns="urn:com:ssn:schema:export:v2.0:SSNExportFormat.xsd" Version="2.0" DocumentID="aebjjjjd-59de-4405-ac0b-50e33b0b4f4b-1" JobID="3354"   ExportID="aeb5bf7d-59de-4405-er0b-50e33b0b4f4b" RunID="20430452"     CreationTime="2015-12-21T13:55:00.807-05:00" StartTime="2015-12-21T09:55:00.000-  05:00" EndTime="2015-12-21T13:55:00.000-05:00">

    <IRD NumberINTVs="3" EndTime="2015-12-21T12:00:00.000-05:00" StartTime="2015-   12-21T09:00:00.000-05:00" INTVLength="60">
    <INTV GatewayCollectedTime="2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00"                             INTVSequenceNumber="47112" BlockSequenceNumber="0" EndTime="2015-12-21T10:00:00.000-05:00">
        <INTVStatus>SERV_HST</INTVStatus>
        <RD U="kWh" BEV="0.0379" Val="0" RV="0" port="1"/>
        <RD U="kWh" BEV="0.0379" Val="0" RV="0" port="2"/>
        <RD U="Vrms" BEV="231.0000" Val="231.0000" RV="231" port="3"/>
    </INTV>
         <INTV GatewayCollectedTime="2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00"     INTVSequenceNumber="47113" BlockSequenceNumber="0" EndTime="2015-12-21T11:00:00.000-05:00">
          <INTVStatus>SERV_HST</INTVStatus>
        <RD U="kWh" BEV="0.0379" Val="0" RV="0" port="1"/>
        <RD U="kWh" BEV="0.0379" Val="0" RV="0" port="2"/>
        <RD U="Vrms" BEV="231.0000" Val="231.0000" RV="231" port="3"/>
          </INTV>
          <INTV GatewayCollectedTime="2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00"                                                                                   INTVSequenceNumber="47114" BlockSequenceNumber="0" EndTime="2015-12-  21T12:00:00.000-05:00">
           <INTVStatus>SERV_HST</INTVStatus>
           <RD U="kWh" BEV="0.0379" Val="0" RV="0" port="1"/>
           <RD U="kWh" BEV="0.0379" Val="0" RV="0" port="2"/>
           <RD U="Vrms" BEV="231.0000" Val="231.0000" RV="231" port="3"/>
    </INTV>
</IRD>
```

Problem is I do not see any outputs for the file when running the code above

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is you have an undeclared namespace and have multiple levels of related data (i.e., the tree nature of XML). Hence, `xmlToList()` might not work as you need to look across nodes.

Consider pulling individual node sets and binding the lists to dataframe. Below declares manual namespace, `ns`. Replicate `rep()` is used for the parent node to correspond to each child node.

```
library(XML)

a<-xmlParse(file.choose())

# EXTRACT NODE SETS
INTV <- getNodeSet(a, '//ns:INTV', 
                   c(ns="urn:com:ssn:schema:export:v2.0:SSNExportFormat.xsd"), xmlAttrs)
INTVStatus <- getNodeSet(a, '//ns:INTVStatus', 
                   c(ns="urn:com:ssn:schema:export:v2.0:SSNExportFormat.xsd"), xmlValue)
RD <- getNodeSet(a, '//ns:RD', 
                   c(ns="urn:com:ssn:schema:export:v2.0:SSNExportFormat.xsd"), xmlAttrs)

# COMBINE LISTS INTO DATA FRAME
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, rep(INTV,3)), 
                 INTVStatus = unlist(rep(INTVStatus,3)), 
                 do.call(rbind, RD))

write.csv(df, 'Output.csv')
#       GatewayCollectedTime   INTVSequenceNumber   BlockSequenceNumber               EndTime     INTVStatus        U          BEV      Val     RV      port
#1      2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00       47112       0       2015-12-21T10:00:00.000-05:00       SERV_HST        kWh     0.0379      0       0       1
#2      2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00       47113       0       2015-12-21T11:00:00.000-05:00       SERV_HST        kWh     0.0379      0       0       2
#3      2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00       47114       0       2015-12-21T12:00:00.000-05:00       SERV_HST        Vrms  231.0000      231     231     3
#4      2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00       47112       0       2015-12-21T10:00:00.000-05:00       SERV_HST        kWh     0.0379      0       0       1
#5      2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00       47113       0       2015-12-21T11:00:00.000-05:00       SERV_HST        kWh     0.0379      0       0       2
#6      2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00       47114       0       2015-12-21T12:00:00.000-05:00       SERV_HST        Vrms  231.0000      231     231     3
#7      2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00       47112       0       2015-12-21T10:00:00.000-05:00       SERV_HST        kWh     0.0379      0       0       1
#8      2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00       47113       0       2015-12-21T11:00:00.000-05:00       SERV_HST        kWh     0.0379      0       0       2
#9      2015-12-21T12:05:02.257-05:00       47114       0       2015-12-21T12:00:00.000-05:00       SERV_HST        Vrms  231.0000      231     231     3
```